# How to implement a tree structure from parsed data in Python

Tags: python, parsing, tree, structure

I am looking for an efficient way to parse data like the ones quoted bellow (one record at a time):

```
(00000001,([xx1#xx2,xx3#[xx4#[xx5#[xx6#0],xx8#false]]]))
(00000002,([xx1,xx3#[xx4#[xx5#[xx6#1,xx11#1],xx8#true#1],xx9#xx10]]))
```

and then print everything from root down to the leafs. The key things to remember are:

1. we go down \ create a new level as long as symbol ] has been parsed
2. we stay on the same level as long as symbol , has been parsed
3. we don't bothered to update a value, however, we have to go down a
   level as long as symbol # has been parsed

The output must look like this:

```
root>xx1>xx2
root>xx3>xx4>xx5>xx6>0
root>xx3>xx4>xx5>xx11>1
root>xx3>xx4>xx8>true>1
root>xx3>xx4>xx8>false
root>xx3>xx9>xx10
```

Any hint is more than welcome!

Comment: It's difficult to see the connection between the input and the output. Why is there no `xx3>xx4>xx5>xx6>1`?

Comment: Hi @FrancisAvila simply because, as I said above, we do not need to worry about the updates, which means that, xx3>xx4>xx5>xx6>1 and xx3>xx4>xx5>xx6>0 are BOTH accepted!